# i wont to make the device vibrate when press down and stop if i move my finger

Tags: android

how can i make the device vibrate if i press down and stop vibrate if i move my finger of ?? now this work with the sound but it not working with the vibrate and this is the code
`

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == arg1.getAction())
        {
            mp.start();
            df= (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        }
        else
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == arg1.getAction())
            {

                mp.stop();
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                    try {
                        df.wait(arg1.getDownTime());
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //df.cancel();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });


    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You're not starting the vibration in ACTION_DOWN, you're simply getting the VibratorService without using it. You need to call:

```
public abstract void vibrate (long[] pattern, int repeat)
```

Like this:

```
df.vibrate(new long[]{300}, 0);
```

Then cancel it with

```
df.cancel();
```

Also, you need this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```